# Problem starting win8 ISO in VMware virtual machine

Tags: windows-8, vmware

i have installed vmware workstation and trying install win8 like this :

[image]

but i get this error:

```
Unable to change virtual machine power state: This host supports Intel VT-x, but Intel VT-x is disabled.
Intel VT-x might be disabled if it has been disabled in the BIOS/firmware settings or the host has not been power-cycled since changing this setting.
(1) Verify that the BIOS/firmware settings enable Intel VT-x and disable 'trusted execution.'
(2) Power-cycle the host if either of these BIOS/firmware settings have been changed.
(3) Power-cycle the host if you have not done so since installing VMware Workstation.
(4) Update the host's BIOS/firmware to the latest version.
This host does not support "Intel EPT" hardware assisted MMU virtualization.
Module 'CPUIDEarly' power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

so what do you think?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Enable virtualization in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks i will do it soon.